# Regularity of a finite borel measure on the compact subsets of $\mathbb{R^d}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures

> *Proposition:* Let $\mu$ be a borel measure such that $\mu(\Bbb{R^d})<+\infty$ Then $\mu$ is regular, i.e $\mu(A)=\inf\{\mu(G)|G \supset A, \text{  G  open}\}=\sup\{\mu(K)|K \subseteq A, \text{  K  compact}\}$

Using this ,i have to prove that if a Borel measure on $\Bbb{R^d}$ has the property that $\mu(K)< +\infty$ for every compact subset $K$ then ti is regular.

In my attempt i put $\mu_n(A)=\mu(A \cap B(0,n))$ where $B(0,n)$ is the closed ball with radious $n$.

$\mu_n$ satisfies the above proposition and also $\sup_n \mu_n= \mu$.

So i managed to prove the one equality.

To prove the second i was given the hint to put $\mu_n(A)=\mu(A \cap Q_n)$ where $Q_n$ is a dyadic cube, and $\Bbb{R^d}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}Q_n$

Also $\mu=\sum_n \mu_n$.

Now how can i use this technique to prove the second equality which involves the infimum?

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know the Riesz Representation Theorem?

Comment: Yes but i want a solution based on the technique i mentioned...but you can post an answer if you want for the diversity of choices and strategies

Comment: Yes, never mind that, I just read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Show that there exist $0<r_1< r_2 < \dots \to \infty$ such that $\mu(\{x:|x|= r_k\}) = 0.$ Then consider the open sets $B(0,r_1), \{ r_1< |x| < r_2\}, \{ r_2< |x| < r_3\}, \dots.$